# How to sort list of files in php

Tags: php, sorting

I have used glob function to read directory

```
        foreach (glob("$path/*.jpg") as $file) {
            array_push($row['images'], $files);
        }
```

The output i get from the above approach is given bellow

```
    [
        "..\/images\/items\/item-16\/img-0.jpg",
        "..\/images\/items\/item-16\/img-1.jpg",
        "..\/images\/items\/item-16\/img-10.jpg",
        "..\/images\/items\/item-16\/img-11.jpg",
        "..\/images\/items\/item-16\/img-12.jpg",
        "..\/images\/items\/item-16\/img-13.jpg",
        "..\/images\/items\/item-16\/img-14.jpg",
        "..\/images\/items\/item-16\/img-15.jpg",
        "..\/images\/items\/item-16\/img-16.jpg",
        "..\/images\/items\/item-16\/img-2.jpg",
        "..\/images\/items\/item-16\/img-3.jpg",
        "..\/images\/items\/item-16\/img-4.jpg",
        "..\/images\/items\/item-16\/img-5.jpg",
        "..\/images\/items\/item-16\/img-6.jpg",
        "..\/images\/items\/item-16\/img-7.jpg",
        "..\/images\/items\/item-16\/img-8.jpg",
        "..\/images\/items\/item-16\/img-9.jpg"
    ]
```

I want to sort in order like this.

```
    [
        "..\/images\/items\/item-16\/img-0.jpg",
        "..\/images\/items\/item-16\/img-1.jpg",
        "..\/images\/items\/item-16\/img-2.jpg",
        "..\/images\/items\/item-16\/img-3.jpg",
        "..\/images\/items\/item-16\/img-4.jpg",
        "..\/images\/items\/item-16\/img-5.jpg",
        "..\/images\/items\/item-16\/img-6.jpg",
        "..\/images\/items\/item-16\/img-7.jpg",
        "..\/images\/items\/item-16\/img-8.jpg",
        "..\/images\/items\/item-16\/img-9.jpg",
        "..\/images\/items\/item-16\/img-10.jpg",
        "..\/images\/items\/item-16\/img-11.jpg",
        "..\/images\/items\/item-16\/img-12.jpg",
        "..\/images\/items\/item-16\/img-13.jpg",
        "..\/images\/items\/item-16\/img-14.jpg",
        "..\/images\/items\/item-16\/img-15.jpg",
        "..\/images\/items\/item-16\/img-16.jpg"

    ]
```

I've also used php `sort()` to sort the names of file, but no luck, any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: [`natsort`](http://php.net/manual/function.natsort.php)

Comment: u use asort($array,SORT_NATURAL); or sort($aa,SORT_NATURAL);